# Invariance of superstring action under super-Weyl transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, symmetry, supersymmetry, spinors

Keeping with the notation on page 178 of the text "Basic concepts of string theory", in superstring theory, consider the action
\begin{align}
S=\frac{1}{8 \pi} \int d^2\sigma e \left(\frac{2}{\alpha} h^{\alpha \beta} \partial_{\alpha} X^{\mu} \partial_{\beta} X_{\mu} + 2 i \bar{\psi}^{\mu} \rho^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha}\psi_{\mu} -i \bar{\chi}_{\alpha} \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu}\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}} \partial_{\beta} X_{\mu} -\frac{i}{4} \bar{\chi}_{\beta} \psi_{\mu} \right)\right),
\end{align}
where $\chi_{\alpha}$ denotes the gravatino, $h^{\alpha \beta}$ the worldsheet metric, and so on..., and $\rho^0 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$, $\rho^1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$, so we have the relation $\rho^{\alpha}\rho_{\beta}\rho_{\alpha}=0$.

Then this action can be shown to be invariant under super-Weyl transformations 
\begin{align}
\delta_{\eta}\chi_{\alpha}&=\rho_{\alpha}\eta,\\
\delta_{\eta}(\text{others})&=0,
\end{align}
with $\eta(\sigma, \tau)$ a Majorana spinor parameter.

I'm having trouble showing invariance here. From $\delta_{\eta}\chi_{\alpha}$, we know
$\delta_{\eta}\bar{\chi}_{\alpha} = \bar{\eta}\rho_{\alpha}$. Thus, 
\begin{align}
\delta_{\eta}S&=\frac{1}{8 \pi} \int d^2\sigma e \left(-i (\delta_{\eta}\bar{\chi}_{\alpha}) \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu}\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}} \partial_{\beta} X_{\mu} -\frac{i}{4} \bar{\chi}_{\beta} \psi_{\mu} \right)-\frac{1}{4} \bar{\chi}_{\alpha} \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu} (\delta_{\eta}\bar{\chi}_{\beta}) \psi_{\mu} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{8 \pi} \int d^2\sigma e \left(-i \bar{\eta}\rho_{\alpha} \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu}\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}} \partial_{\beta} X_{\mu} -\frac{i}{4} \bar{\chi}_{\beta} \psi_{\mu} \right)-\frac{1}{4} \bar{\chi}_{\alpha} \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu} \bar{\eta}\rho_{\beta} \psi_{\mu} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{8 \pi} \int d^2\sigma e \left(-\frac{1}{4} \bar{\chi}_{\alpha} \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu} \bar{\eta}\rho_{\beta} \psi_{\mu} \right)\\
\end{align}
but I don't see how $\bar{\chi}_{\alpha} \rho^{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \psi^{\mu} \bar{\eta}\rho_{\beta} \psi_{\mu}=0$, as given $\psi$ and $\bar{\eta}$ are spinors, and we can't simply commute $\rho_{\beta}$ with them and use the relation $\rho^{\alpha}\rho_{\beta}\rho_{\alpha}=0$ we use for the other term?

Comment: I guess you want to use an something like $\sum_a (\rho^a)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} (\rho_a)_{\beta\dot{\beta}} =2\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}$

Comment: In GSW eq. 4.3.83 this part of the action is written as $S_4 = - \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int d^2 \sigma e \overline{\psi}_{\mu} \psi^{\mu} \overline{\chi}_{\alpha} \rho^{\beta} \rho^{\alpha} \chi_{\beta}$ for which the identity follows immediately, is it re-written your way using a Fierz identity maybe.

Comment: I agree. To me it looks like you want a $(1/2,0) \otimes (0,1/2)=(1/2,1/2)$ Fierz identity, ie $\psi_\alpha \bar{\chi}_{\dot{\alpha}}=\frac12 (\psi \rho_a \bar{\chi})(\rho^a)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}$.